# Android Studio build file R broken

Tags: java, android, build, corruption

I am working on an android app which has worked and been tested many times. Today, however, in attempting to run the application for further testing, I have encountered the following error message:

```
C:\Users\1000\AndroidStudioProjects\WarofSol\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\blacktentdigital\warofsol\R.java
Error:(1251, 32) error: identifier expected
Error:(1251, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1251, 35) error: identifier expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

>Information:BUILD FAILED
```

The problem is in the `R.java` file (as listed above). It is a generated file, so I've never touched it.

The offending line is this:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int 3=0x7f020000;
```

Hover over the offending line gives the following warning: `"Identifier expected | Unexpected token"`

Comparisons to other R files reveal that the "3" is not supposed to be a 3, and is evidently corrupted.

Attempts to replace the line or file with older backed-up versions have failed to produce any result because (evidently) the file is regenerating the wrong way each time I attempt the build, and I have no idea what might cause this. As I say, the problem sprang up suddenly without any provocation of which I am aware.

I've also attempted closing the program and restarting the computer to no avail.

Any ideas as to what might cause this and how it might be fixed?

Comment: Do you have any drawable called 3 (.png or other)?

Comment: I hope we get a response about what was wrong and what fixed it. It may be obvious based on the (first) Answer below that an illegal name (`3`) has been used, but I'd like to hear that from @Truth.

Comment: 3.png - a typographical error - was exactly the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get the Same error when i have defined a String in xml file like this.

```
<string name="3">Settings</string>
```

Error:

```
Error:(1426, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(1426, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(1426, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Solution: `Resource name must begin with character`.
 So i have just change String like `<string name="S3">Settings</string>` and it worked.

So just check if you have any resource name 3 in all your resource file(string.xml, style.xml, attrs.xml) and folder(drawable, layout).

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from java documentation:

> > A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

And you named drawable with digit, that caused the problem.